# sorting range based on other column values in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, excel-2010, office-2010

I have excel sheet contain data as below:

[image: Excel data]

what we need is sorting range D2:E10 based on Column A values

we need result to be like this:

[image: RequiredResult]

Is there any method allow us to do that?

(we recommend not to use macro if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the closest solution with no macros is

select column a and d

use conditional fomat -> highlight cells Rules --> duplicated values

now all douplicted values cell color chaned

select range A2:B7 and custom sort using cell color, not colored cells at bottom

do the same with range D2:E10

hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

I find some workaround solution

in cell F2 I used

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;$D$2:$E$20;1;FALSE)
```

and in cell G2

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;$D$2:$E$20;2;FALSE)
```

copy formulas to range F3: G10

this gives me some result but some data in range D2:E10 lost such as D4, D5 ...etc (not copied in column F and G )